# Simple HTML DOM Thinks a String is an Object

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM to convert HTML emails into text emails. I keep getting the error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom as array

which I get when trying to pass an object into $html = str_get_html($body); Only it shouldn't be an object, it should be a string. It works fine running it locally on my computer, but not on my web server. What's up?

```
include '../classes/parser.class.php';
$textEmail = convertToText($_POST['htmlEmail']);

function convertToText($body)
{
    $html = str_get_html($body);
    $links = $html->find('a');

    // Replace links with text (http://www.link.com)
    foreach($links as $l)
    {
        $l->outertext = $l->innertext . ' (' . $l->href . ')';
    }

    // Save progress back into a string
    $str = $html; # also tried $str = $html->save();
    $html = str_get_html($str);

    // Only grab the text
    $text = $html->find('text');
    foreach($text as $t)
    {
        $textBody .= $t . "\n";
    }

    return $textBody;
}
```

Comment: on what line do you have an error? which kine of the script does it piont to?

Comment: The error points to line 922 of the parser class, but I looked at it and don't think I can fix the class easily.

Comment: Did my answer help at all? :)